# Can I download the executable for any developed or listed application that developed using SO API?

Tags: discussion

I saw the StackList and the apps. May I know How can I use those applications?

Can I use it ? Are they opensource?

Can I download the executable for any developed or listed application that developed using SO API?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what's being asked here, but I'll try to answer some of it.

StackList itself does have an API. See [here](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/api/).

As for the apps themselves, almost all of them are open source. A fair amount of them have precompiled executables you can use. Just visit [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app) page and go through the items.